# swipl increment cursor in recursive function

Tags: recursion, prolog, tail-recursion

I am very green with Prolog. I have a 7-by-7 grid and for each cell I store the `X`, the `Y`, and two other things, like this: `cell(1, 1, 0, 0)`.

I want to traverse the grid and reset the values of the cells if they are not given, so I created these functions:

```
given(X, Y):- (cell(X, Y, start, _) ; cell(X, Y, end, _)).
reset_cell(X, Y):- not(given(X, Y)), cell(X, Y, 0, 0).
reset_grid(8, _):- write('finished resetting').
reset_grid(X, 8):- X1 is X + 1, reset_cell(X1, 1), reset_grid(X1, 1).
reset_grid(X, Y):- reset_cell(X, Y), Y1 is Y + 1, reset_grid(X, Y1).
```

But this results in an endless loop because in the last line apparently the parameter passed to the `reset_grid` function remains at value `1`. What am I doing wrong?

*Edit:* I forgot to mention that I call the function like this: `?- reset_grid(1, 1).`

*Edit 2:* (new version as per Sergey's instructions):

```
reset_grid(X, _):- X > 7, write('finished resetting').
reset_grid(X, Y):- Y > 7, X1 is X + 1, reset_cell(X1, 1), reset_grid(X1, 1).
reset_grid(X, Y):- X < 8, Y < 8, reset_cell(X, Y), Y1 is Y + 1, reset_grid(X, Y1).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you have a call `reset_grid(1, 8)`, your `reset_grid(X, 8)` clause fires, but after that `reset_grid(X, Y)` also fires.

To fix this you can add cut '!' to the `reset_grid(X, 8)` clause or add `Y < 8` to the `reset_grid(X, Y)`, or do both (to get a so-called 'green cut').

The similar problem with call `reset_grid(8, 8)`: `reset_grid(8, _)` will match, but after that `reset_grid(X, Y)` will match. Fix in the similar manner.

*UPDATE.*

Try to change you reset cell definition to just logging X and Y. With this code:

```
reset_cell(X, Y) :- write([X, Y]), nl.
reset_grid(X, _):- X > 7, write('finished resetting').
reset_grid(X, Y):- Y > 7, X1 is X + 1, reset_cell(X1, 1), reset_grid(X1, 1).
reset_grid(X, Y):- X < 8, Y < 8, reset_cell(X, Y), Y1 is Y + 1, reset_grid(X, Y1).
```

I get this result:

```
?- reset_grid(1, 1).
[1,1]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[1,4]
[1,5]
[1,6]
[1,7]
[2,1]
[2,1]
[2,2]
[2,3]
[2,4]
[2,5]
[2,6]
[2,7]
[3,1]
[3,1]
[3,2]
[3,3]
[3,4]
[3,5]
[3,6]
[3,7]
[4,1]
[4,1]
[4,2]
[4,3]
[4,4]
[4,5]
[4,6]
[4,7]
[5,1]
[5,1]
[5,2]
[5,3]
[5,4]
[5,5]
[5,6]
[5,7]
[6,1]
[6,1]
[6,2]
[6,3]
[6,4]
[6,5]
[6,6]
[6,7]
[7,1]
[7,1]
[7,2]
[7,3]
[7,4]
[7,5]
[7,6]
[7,7]
[8,1]
finished resetting
true ;
false.
```

So the loop works and terminates. Maybe the problem in the last call `reset_cell(8, 1)`? Otherwise it's with the `reset_cell` predicate itself or the predicates called from `reset_cell`. Show the rest of your code so it can be tested.

Comment: Your code in the comment doesn't look right to me. Just add `Y < 8, X < 8` to the last clause of your original code from the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't format the code right. Yes, I have added the code. Please check me original post. Still looping endlessly.

Comment: if I do write(Y) in the last line I can actually see that Y is never incremented.

Comment: Thank you vey much. Your solution works. It was stupid call I was making (for testing purposes) inside function `given(X, Y)`. So the recursive function was calling `given(X, Y)` and `given(X, Y)` was calling the recursive function, that's why there was an endless loop.

Comment: @corneliu you should avoid the incorrect term of "function" for prolog "predicate". Prolog has *predicates*, not *functions*. They don't do the same thing as functions.